# Error while initializing MIDlet object SecurityException - Java me

Tags: java, security, class, exception, constructor

I am working on an application on Java me. 
All i want to do is to access members from a MIDlet from another class.

I have a class mainFrm which is the main form.
And i want to access some non-static methods from another class.

And my code is the following:

```
mainFrm myForm = new mainFrm(); //Initialize the object
myForm.aNonStaticMethod(); //Call the method
```

However when calling the constructor i get a Security exception.

I think that i miss something!
Any help would be gratefull!
Thnx!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with MIDP, Security Exceptions are primarily caused by lack of signing, and it usually is only thrown when trying to access a class that is placed in a "trusted" domain (i.e. not accessible unless the JAD is signed). See: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/ for more info on domains and permissions.

My guess is that in your mainFrm() constructor you are accessing a class that cannot be accessed via untrusted domain.  99% of these exceptions are due to HTTP or Sockets.  Are you using those classes in the constructor?

Comment: I figured it out! In my second class i just passed the reference of my first class and now it works okay!! Thnx for your answer!!